# Showing content based on a nav link clicked

Tags: javascript, html, navbar

I have a menu selection that looks like this:

```
<ul class = "menu">
    <li><a href="#about" class="aboutNav">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact" class="contactNav">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#misc" class="miscNav">Misc</a></li>
</ul>
```

I'm trying to make content associated with each of these links show on click and hide all other content. The JS I'm using looks as follows:

```
$('.menu li .aboutNav').click(function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $('.wrapper').hide();
   $('.misc').hide();
   $('.contact').hide();
   $('.about').show();});
```

I want to have a function like this for each menu element, but currently it isn't working for all the elements in the menu. I've looked at other threads with the same problem I'm having but none of them seem to directly apply to the way I'm doing it.

I just started learning html, js, css so I could be going about this the wrong way and that's why the other threads haven't really helped.

EDIT: Here's a pastebin of all of my HTML http://pastebin.com/FjcNXGkY

Comment: It can be much more helpful if you use jsfiddle to share code like this: http://jsfiddle.net/3Lz18sgp/

Comment: Please don't put your code in a pastebin. Put it here, and narrow it down to the relevant parts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A more efficient way would be to add the same class to all links and another class to all content items...

HTML:

```
<ul class="menu">
  <li><a href="#about" class="menu-btn">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact" class="menu-btn">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#misc" class="menu-btn">Misc</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="menu-content about">About</div>
<div class="menu-content contact">Contact</div>
<div class="menu-content misc">Misc</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var $content = $('.menu-content');

function showContent(type) {
  // this assumes that you really must select
  // the content using a class and not an ID (which you've 
  // referenced in the href)
  $content.hide().filter('.' + type).show();
}

$('.menu').on('click', '.menu-btn', function(e) {
  // get the type to pass to showContent by grabbing
  // the hash from the anchor href and removing the first
  // character (the #)
  showContent(e.currentTarget.hash.slice(1));
  e.preventDefault();
}); 

// show 'about' content only on page load (if you want)
showContent('about');
```

Demo on jsbin: http://jsbin.com/hagonesuwo/edit?html,js,output

------------------------------------- **EDIT** -------------------------------------

I have just seen your edit with a link to your pastebin. If there is only one content item for each nav item then you can use IDs instead...

HTML:

```
<ul class="menu">
  <li><a href="#about" class="menu-btn">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact" class="menu-btn">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#misc" class="menu-btn">Misc</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="about" class="menu-content">About</div>
<div id="contact" class="menu-content">Contact</div>
<div id="misc" class="menu-content">Misc</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var $content = $('.menu-content');

function showContent(selector) {
  $content.hide();
  $(selector).show();
}

$('.menu').on('click', '.menu-btn', function(e) {
  showContent(e.currentTarget.hash);
  e.preventDefault();
}); 

// show '#about' content only on page load (if you want)
showContent('#about');
```

This would be much better as it would mean the navigation would still jump to the relevant content if JS was disabled or failed to download for any reason.

Comment: I like this approach a lot, but here is a slightly different take using `data` attributes http://jsfiddle.net/p7oqn7w1/ if you are using css classes to store data this is can be cleaner to keep your data separate from your style

Comment: I originally did something similar (http://jsbin.com/xuyagubuku/edit?html,js,output) but they were using classes on theirs so tried not to deviate too far with my answer. I agree data attributes would be better :)

Answer (score 1):

This solution assumes that the `a` elements will only have a single class.

```
$('.menu li a').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".wrapper,.misc,.content,.about").hide(); // Hide all.
    $("." + this.className.slice(0,-3)).show(); // Show one based on the class
});
```

It binds the same handler to all the `a` elements.

When clicked, it hides all the targeted elements, and then slices away the `"Nav"` from the `.className` to create a selector to choose the one to display.

Not sure what `.wrapper` does, since it's not in your HTML.

Comment: Wrapper is content that shows up by default when you land on the home page, sorry I forgot to mention that, going over your solution now thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".menu").children().click(function(){
    $(".menu").children(function(){
        $("."+$(this).attr("class").replace("Nav","")).hide();
    })
    $("."+$(this).attr("class").replace("Nav","")).show();
})
```

This would be a universal solution, considering that you can have any menu item with class "someItemNav"; if it's clicked any items are hidden and only "someItem" is shown.

Comment: He's not hiding the menu items.

Comment: There's a display container related to each menu item. When clicking an item, it hides the currently shown container and shows the one related to the click. He should have included all the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of problems with your JS:

- you select items by class `.misc` instead of ID `#misc`
- the way you coded the click is very rigid. Make it more elastic like:

  ```
  $('.menu').on('click', 'li', function (e) {
      $('article').hide();
      var id = $(this).find('a').attr('href'); // $(this) is the clicked LI
      $(id).show();    
  })
  ```

I assume all items with IDs #about, #contact etc. are simply `article` HTML elements and I hide them all before showing the right one. Hope this helps.

**EDIT**

Or even a bit more elegant hiding the other contents:

```
$('.menu').on('click', 'li', function (e) {
    var id = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
    $(id).show().siblings().hide();    
})
```